# Split column value at delimiter

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a column name called as 'STATS1' in one of my Oracle DBs. Following are the field values that are under this column -

```
010112.TMD.ORG1
010112.F99.DEFAULT
010112.F20
010112.F16.ORG2.XYZ12
```

Now, I want to write an sql query to split the above strings into multiple. Below is the O/P format that I am seeking for using SQL substr and instr functions.

```
ACCOUNT     GRPID   ORG     REL
=======     =====   ====    ====
010112      TMD     ORG1
010112      F99     DEFAULT
010112      F20
010112      F16     ORG2    XYZ12
```

Comment: Format your input and output in a table. It is not readable.

Comment: You already know you'll be using substr and instr, so where is your code?

Comment: No I am able to split the string till first period. the problem arise here is how to split for the 2nd part, 3rd and so on..

Comment: Have you looked at the [`instr` documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e26088/functions080.htm#SQLRF00651), particularly the `occurrence` argument?

Comment: Yaa...I did use the Occurence Argument in my substring function. But that is not so simple since the 2nd part is not consistently ending with period always. For dome of the strings there is no period and it just ended there. So, we have to use some conditions...I hope so!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
select 
  regexp_substr(column, '[^.]+', 1, 1) as account
, regexp_substr(column, '[^.]+', 1, 2) as grpid
, regexp_substr(column, '[^.]+', 1, 3) as org
, regexp_substr(column, '[^.]+', 1, 4) as rel
from your_table
```

Answer (score 1):

Just to show a less elegant solution by using SUBSTR and INSTR instead of REGEXP_SUBSTR :-) You can add delimiters to your column in order to use INSTR without any danger of not finding the nth delimiter.

```
with formatted as
(
  select '.' || col || '....' as col
  from mytable
)
select 
  substr(col, instr(col, '.', 1, 1) + 1, instr(col, '.', 1, 2) - instr(col, '.', 1, 1) - 1) as aaa,
  substr(col, instr(col, '.', 1, 2) + 1, instr(col, '.', 1, 3) - instr(col, '.', 1, 2) - 1) as aaa,
  substr(col, instr(col, '.', 1, 3) + 1, instr(col, '.', 1, 4) - instr(col, '.', 1, 3) - 1) as aaa,
  substr(col, instr(col, '.', 1, 4) + 1, instr(col, '.', 1, 5) - instr(col, '.', 1, 4) - 1) as aaa
from formatted;
```